# Problems wiring up delegate between views

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates

I'm trying to wire up the delegate in KGModal to MainView, but it doesnt work. Basically I show SecondViewController in [KGModal (Github)](https://github.com/kgn/KGModal), and when dismissing the KGModal view i want the MainView to know that through the delegate. Any ideas? (sorry for bad explanation). Can't get it to work.

KGModal.h

```
@class KGModal;
@protocol KGModalDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)modalControllerDidFinish:(KGModal *)controller;
@end

@interface KGModal : NSObject {
    UIButton *dismissButton;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <KGModalDelegate> delegate;
```

KGModal.m

```
-(void)dismissButtonPressed:(id)sender {
        [self.delegate modalControllerDidFinish:self];
        [self hideAnimated:self.animateWhenDismissed];   
}
```

MainView.h

```
@interface MainView : UIViewController <KGModalDelegate> 

@property(weak) id<KGModalDelegate> delegate;
```

MainView.m

```
- (void)modalControllerDidFinish:(KGModal *)controller{ 
    NSLog(@"Dismissed.");
}

-(IBAction)modalShowing {

SecondViewController *view2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

        KGModal *kg = [[KGModal alloc] init];
        kg.delegate = self;

        [[KGModal sharedInstance] showWithContentView:view2.view andAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: There's absolutely nothing magical about a delegate.  It's just a pointer to an object that implements a protocol.  If you actually execute ` [self.delegate modalControllerDidFinish:self];`, and if `self.delegate` is set, then `modalControllerDidFinish` will be called in the instance addressed by `self.delegate`.

Comment: (It appears to me that you're setting the delegate in a different instance of KGModal than the one that you're presenting.)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I set the delegate to different instances of KGModal.

```
KGModal *kgm = [KGModal sharedInstance];

kgm.delegates = self;
[kgm showWithContentView:view2.view andAnimated:YES];
```

Thanks to Hot Licks!